# while loop won't read file, or print out line java

Tags: java, class, constructor, while-loop

I have a with the **hentAntall** method in my code below. It's supposed to find the search word inside a txt file. I don't get any sort of error. It just won't print out any of the two possible lines.

This method has to access a constructor first to get the search word, and then it has to find that search word in the txt file and add to count. The constructor gets the search word from another class. Like this **new lolz("searchword").hentAntall();**

(I apologize for the stupid naming in this program, but it's just a copy of one of my programs, and I'm just trying to correct it without screwing up the original.)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lolz {

  private String sokeord=null;
  private int antall = 0;
  // Constructor
  lolz(String searchword) throws Exception{
    this.sokeord = searchword;
  }

  //toString method, to print in the same format.
  @Override
  public String toString(){
      return "\nSokeordet er: " + sokeord+ "\n";
  }

  // Gets the ammount of the searchword
  public int hentAntall() throws Exception{
    File file = new File("Hvorfor.txt");
    Scanner readfile = new Scanner(file);
    while (readfile.hasNextLine()){
           String nextline = readfile.nextLine();
            if (nextline.equalsIgnoreCase(sokeord)) {
            antall ++;
            System.out.println("Antallet av:" + sokeord + "er " + antall);
        }
        else {System.out.println("Error no such search word in the given text");}
    }
    return antall;
  }

  // void methode to increase the count of a searcheword.
  void oekAntall() {
    antall++;
  }
}
```

This is the other class that calls on this method, and also give information to the constructor.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new lolz("fungerer").hentAntall();

}}
```

Also tried some of the suggestions and they did not work, I only get a the message Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: show us your main class, and where you call the function

Comment: u never actually read anything

Comment: Yeah, this method is not called in your code..

Comment: Where are you calling the hentAntall() method

Comment: did not you want to say readfile.nextLine()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Issue:

> **You are trying to compare a Scanner variable with a String Variable**?!!!

**Explanation**:

you try to compare content of Scanner which is

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match
>   valid=true][need input=false][source
>   closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal
>   separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive
>   suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

with content of a String variable.

---

You do not read the each line with following

```
if (readfile.equals(sokeord)) {
```

You Should have

```
 if (readfile.nextLine().equals(sokeord)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, my bad but even though i fixed that, the problem is still not resolved. I have now posted the main method to see if there are any problems there.

Comment: No other errors, i just get the line process finished with exit code 0

Comment: No, i want it to print out the amount of the search word in the given txt, or post a error message saying it could not find the word. And right now it only gives me code 0 message.

Comment: Your explanation is lacking. No instances of two classes should ever equal each other as this violates the equality contract. It has nothing to do with all those listed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
readfile.equals(sokeord)
```

Which is comparing an instance of type `Scanner` with a `String` (never going to be `true`). You need to read a line and compare that.

```
String line = readfile.nextLine();
if(line.equals(sokeord)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a main method to your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    hentAntall();
}
```

You will have to make hentAntall() static or create an instance of lolz class and call it that way.

Also change:

```
while (readfile.hasNext()){
    if (readfile.nextLine().contains(sokeord)) {
```

You need to actually read the input and then check if sokeord exists in the line or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your hentAntall method should be like this:

```
public int hentAntall() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("Hvorfor.txt");
    Scanner readfile = new Scanner(file);
    while (readfile.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = readfile.next();
        if (word.contains(sokeord)) {
            antall++;
            System.out.println("Antallet av:" + sokeord + "er " + antall);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Error no such search word in the given text: ");
        }
    }
    readfile.close();
    return antall;
}
```

Don't forget to close the Scanner resource to avoid leaks.